# Check my work: line integral of $\langle e^z,e^{x-y},e^y\rangle$ over a triangular path

Tags: integration

> Calculate the line integral of $F=\langle e^z,e^{x-y},e^y\rangle$ over the closed path $C$ connecting the points $ABCA$, where $A = (2,0,0), B = (0,4,0)$ and $C = (0,0,6)$.

To do this, I parameterized each line segment, then calculated $F(r(t))$ and $r'(t)$ for each segment. I then took the integral for each, and summed up the total. I ended up with a complicated answer of:

$$\frac{e^{10}+2e^6-3}{3e^4}+\frac{3e^4}{2}-\frac{65}{6}$$

I'm wondering if I did something wrong. The usual trend with these questions is that it turns out to work nicely. Does anyone get a different answer for this than I did?

Comment: the third component of vector $F$ is a complex?

Comment: @juliogodoy Whoops, that was supposed to be a y. Fixed!

Comment: Sorry, but your complicated answer _is_ correct.  Generally, only the low-numbered line integral problems in a textbook section have "nice" (i.e., integral or rational number) values.  One very quickly graduates to messier evaluations (particularly when transcendental functions or less simple paths are involved)...

Answer (score 1):

for the segment $AB$, we have:
$$r(t)=A+(B-A)t=(2,0,0)+(-2,4,0)t=(2-2t,4t,0)$$
$$r'(t)=B-A=(-2,4,0)$$
then the integral of line in this segment is:
$$\int_0^1(e^0,e^{2-6t},e^{4t})\cdot(-2,4,0)dt=\int_0^1-2+4e^{2-6t}dt=-2+\frac{2}{3}(e^2-e^{-4})$$
now for the $BC$ segment, we have:
$$r(t)=B+(C-B)t=(0,4,0)+(0,-4,6)t=(0,4-4t,6t)$$
$$r'(t)=(0,-4,6)$$
then
$$\int_0^1(e^{6t},e^{4t-4},e^{4-4t})\cdot(0,-4,6)dt=\int_0^1-4e^{4t-4}+6e^{4-4t}dt=$$
$$=\left[-e^{4t-4}-\frac{3}{2}e^{4-4t}\right|_0^1=\left[e^{4t-4}+\frac{3}{2}e^{4-4t}\right|_1^0=e^{-4}+\frac{3}{2}e^4-\frac{5}{2}$$
For $CA$, we have:
$$r(t)=C+(A-C)t=(0,0,6)+(2,0,-6)t=(2,0,6-6t)$$
$$r'(t)=(2,0,-6)$$
then
$$\int_0^1(e^{6-6t},e^2,e^0)\cdot(2,0,-6)dt=\int_0^1 2e^{6-6t}-6dt=-6+\frac{1}{3}\left[ e^{6-6t}\right|_1^0=$$
$$=-6+\frac{1}{3}(e^6-1)=\frac{e^6}{3}+\frac{-19}{3}$$
the final result is:
$$=-2+\frac{2}{3}(e^2-e^{-4})+e^{-4}+\frac{3}{2}e^4-\frac{5}{2}+\frac{e^6}{3}+\frac{-19}{3}$$
God bless you.

Comment: I agree up to your last integral evaluation:  $ \ -6 \ - \ \frac{1}{3} \ = \ -\frac{19}{3} \ $ This will then make the sum of your constant terms equal to $ \ - \frac{65}{6} \ $ , which _is_ what **dubbler26** had found.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help! I appreciate it.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner thanks a lot, i fix the problem

Comment: @dubbler26 you're welcome

Comment: Almost there: you should have either $ \ \frac{e^6}{3} \ - \ \frac{ 19}{3} \ $ or  $ \ \frac{e^6}{3} \ + \ \frac{-19}{3} \ $ .

Comment: @RecklessReckoner thanks again